# can you explain the following java code for image processing?

Tags: java, image-processing

[image]here outdata is buffer of size[8*1024],can you tell me the exactly what will happened after execution of above lines??

Comment: A bit more background would be nice.

Comment: I would suggest start by studying [operators in Java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm).

Comment: Please copy-paste the code, don't just insert an image of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code  looks like it takes an array with rgba values in the format `[R, G, B, A, R, G, B, A...]` and compresses it to  the `[RGBA, RGBA, RGBA...]` format using bitwise operations (`<<` and `&`).

The `& 0xFF` part is called bitmasking, it makes the last 8 bits of the number stay the same, but others are zeroed.

```
0000110011101110 & 0xFF -> 0000000011101110
```

The `number + (number2 << 8)` concatenates the numbers, so the first 8 bits will contain the first number, the second 8 bits will contain the second number

```
10101010 << 8 -> 1010101000000000
10101010 + (11101110 << 8) -> 1110111010101010
```

Comment: @wondra java can't do bitwise operations on anything other than integers, wich are 32 bits, so yes, it's compression

Comment: It is very bold statement that taking 8 bits, implicitly making it 32 and then back 8 is compression.

Comment: @wondra I don't think you understood my answer. The current code takes 4 **32 bit** (they are originally 32 bits, they never were 8 bit) numbers (that's 128 bits), takes their last 8 bits and puts them into 1 **32 bit** number.